# Is there a shorter way to write a function applied to a list in scheme like this?

Tags: lisp, scheme

I'm using R5RS (in racket). Here is my example

```
(map (lambda (x) (list (apply + x) (apply * x))) '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
 -> ((6 6) (15 120))
```

I was just wondering that if there's a built-in function like this

```
(map-apply '(+ *) '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
```

which could produce the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing built-in, but you can write your own:

```
(define (map-apply funcs items)
  (map (lambda (item)
         (map (lambda (func)
                (apply func item))
              funcs))
       items))
```

You'd have to pass in `(list + *)`, not `'(+ *)`, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing these kinds of things often you can abstract the production of the map-function. Thus the rest will be unchanged:

```
;; Makes a function that applies all functions to an argument
(define (make-map-fun . funs)
  (lambda (lis)
     (map (lambda (fun) (apply fun lis)) funs)))

(map (make-map-fun + *) '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
; ==> ((6 6) (15 120))

;; And you can zip with it too
(apply map 
       (lambda l ((make-map-fun + *) l)) 
       '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9))) 
; ==> ((12 28) (15 80) (18 162))
```

Comment: There's no need for macros for that; you can write a pure function implementation of `make-map-fun`, without changing the interface at all (`(define (make-map-fun . funcs) (lambda (args) (map (lambda (func) (apply func args)) funcs)))`). And thus, the usual advice of "only use a macro if necessary", etc. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you still there +firegun?  If you really, really need to pass the function arguments as '(+ *) then your solution would be:

```
(define (map-apply function-names items)
  (let ((funcs (map (lambda (name) (eval name (interaction-environment))) function-names)))
    (map (lambda (item)
           (map (lambda (func)
                  (apply func item))
                funcs))
         items)))
```

Comment: Ewwww. `eval`, really?! Seriously, though, passing in function name symbols rather than function objects is just really broken.

Comment: I prefaced it with 'if you really, really need...' showing my doubt but it is what he shows in his OP.  Could be implementing an interpreter or reading input.